# Android do not increase text in application when device font size changes

Tags: android, font-size

I have an android app, where I use a list of items, for example I have a thumbnail on the left, and some text to right of it.

Everything works fine, but I noticed a problem, when the user increases the font size for his device (not in application, but generally for his device as he is an older person, needs to have bigger letters). As each mobile device has in settings a possibility to change font size - small. medium, large, very large etc.)

However, this change increase also the font size in my application, and then the list of items looks very bad, as the text right of the image comes to multiple lines or even if stays on one line, it looks very bad as it's zoomed, because the device text size is increased.

Normally I use text size in SP (e.g.16sp):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
</TextView>
```

Is there a way to have my app not affected by the device font size settings, as my app has it's own font sizes or there is nothing to do ?

Now if someone needs to have big fonts on his device, he can't use the app normally.

Answer (score 5):

You can override in base activity

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    val config = Configuration(newBase?.resources?.configuration)
    config.fontScale = 1.0f
    applyOverrideConfiguration(config)
}
```

Java:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    Configuration config = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    config.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(config);
}
```

Comment: and possibly in java, not kotlin please? Not a bad idea

Answer (score 4):

Use `dp` instead of `sp` for fontsize of TextView. It will not affect the size of text even after user changes the phone font size because `sp` is scaled by user's font size preference, other than that `dp` and `sp` have same default values.

Comment: thank you, I just tested it, seems working fine. However Android studio suggests to use SP instead of DP, but I can live with that

Comment: @Darksymphony Saniya's answer is correct, using DPs will keep the same scaled size. However, as you saw, Android Studio will complain, because it goes against accessibility rules. If a user increases the system text size, it is usually because cannot see correctly (bad eyesight), therefore using DPs instead of SPs puts your own aesthetic choice over what the user really needs, which is a bad design choice.